# Invalid Object name 'Source' while using merge

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using this in a merge statement but now I am getting the error Invalid object name 'Source'.

I am not getting this error on any of my other merge statements. Source is below. I have anonymized to a certain extent so please let me know if it isn't clear

```
 MERGE dbo.Destination WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS Target
USING
(
SELECT DISTINCT id, col3,   
 CAST(LEFT(DATEADD(m,months,CONVERT(date,CONCAT(origination,'/01'))),7) as   varchar(20))  as CalendarMonth,
 col1, col2,col4 FROM dbo.Staging
) AS Source
ON (Target.ID=Source.id
AND Target.Month=Source.col3)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET
        Target.CalendarMonth=Source.CalendarMonth,
        Target.colF= (SELECT CASE WHEN col1>0 THEN 1 END AS colF FROM Source),
        Target.colD=(SELECT CASE WHEN col4>0 THEN 1 END AS colD
                                    FROM Source),
        Target.colC=(SELECT CASE WHEN col1=0 AND col2=0
                                    THEN 1 END AS colC FROM Source),
        Target.colB(SELECT CASE WHEN col1>0 AND col2
                                    THEN 1 END AS colB FROM Source),
        Target.colG=(SELECT CASE WHEN col1>0 THEN col1 END AS colG FROM Source),
        Target.colE=(SELECT CASE WHEN col4>0 THEN col3 END
                                    AS colE FROM Source),
        Target.PaidMonth=(SELECT CASE WHEN col1=0 AND col2=0
                                    THEN col3 END AS PaidMonth 
                                    FROM Source),
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT
        (Destination Table columns
        )
        VALUES
        (   Source values including derived values from above);

END
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

**UPDATE:**

@Sam cd's recommendation helped where i replaced the select statement in the derived columns with CASE WHEN col4>0 THEN col3 END and so on. Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: Is this an example you copy/pasted?  It isn't a complete statement.

Comment: No, i changed the variable names from my actual code. I probably got a little lazy with the WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET Insert part, my apologies for that. What I meant there was that source values are inserted into target table columns including the derived column calcs from above mapped to the respective target columns.

Comment: That makes sense.  When you do that, it makes it hard to see if there's a syntax error in that part of the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is probably in how you phrase the updates. Using the subquery cancels out the alias. I.e. here SQL would look for a table within your database actually named source, which probably doesn't exist.

```
Target.colF= (SELECT CASE WHEN col1>0 THEN 1 END AS colF FROM Source),
```

You don't need to phrase it like that, since `Source` has been aliased, you can just say

```
Target.colF= CASE WHEN Source.col1>0 THEN 1 END,
```

Comment: I will try this. I had tried replacing Source with the actaul table name within the case statement but that hadn't worked. I will try this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
VALUES
    (   Source values including derived values from above)
```

Is that meant to be a comment?

Comment: I probably got a little lazy with the WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET Insert part, my apologies for that. What I meant there was that source values are inserted into target table columns including the derived column calcs from above mapped to the respective target columns.